# JS caches values of inputs (Laravel)

Tags: javascript, laravel, caching, input

Using Laravel, I have js fill my hidden input

```
self.find('.info').val($(this).val());


<input type="hidden" class="info"
name="bame" value="{{$val}}">
```

after I reload my page all filled inputs remain and the hidden input value is not `{{$val}}` but it is what js assigned it before load.

```
src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}?n=1"></script>
```

or

```
src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}?{{time()}}"></script>
```

does not help

Comment: you can add this things in your $(document) function.

Comment: maybe you can give an example how it should look like?